# MQTT Topic Scaling

Tags: design-patterns, push-notification, cloud, mqtt

I have some quick questions on the functionality of MQTT and just overall push design. So here's a scenario let's say in Twitter's case; Twitter wants to send push notifications to individual user. So let's say you're subscribed to my notification topic when I Tweet. Would this be a proper topic hierarchy and use case for MQTT?

From what I understand from pub/sub systems this would get quite cumbersome. Wouldn't you have to have a topic for each individual user? Is there a limit on topic's in these kind of Systems? How do big applications with millions of users go about sending push notifications?

Comment: What does MQTT stand for?

Comment: MQ Telemetry Transport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling is an issue in any system.

MQTT - well, some brokers, specifically IBM WebSphere MQ, RSMB, and mosquitto - support the concept of bridges - which enable satellite, mesh, and tree hierarchies for topics.

You certainly are unlikely to have millions of clients connecting to a single broker (but all of the above implementations scale well to hundreds of thousands). You need to consider the topic layout and physical hierarchy of brokers, as well as having some load balancing and localisation of connections.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy, I actually just finished watching your lecture on Paho ironically.

Answer (score 2):

YES, MQTT is exactly what you want in your case.

However MQTT is just a protocol, the limit of topic amount is depends on the implement of it. I built my own MQTT server use [Netty](http://netty.io/), and it can push messages to more than a million of clients on single machine. For open source solution, You can check out [mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/) , Which is the most widely used MQTT server written in C. Hope this helps.